# AdMob not showing on real device

Tags: swift, admob, device

I just added adMob into my app.
When I test it on the simulator, the test ad is showing, but when I run it on my real device, I just see a blank view at the bottom( 320*50 )

Is this the way its supposed to be?
Its my first app, and Im not sure if I can upload this for review at the App Store or not?
(I don't get any error)

Here is the code for the ad;

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {

    let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "background")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: backgroundImage)
    self.tabelView.backgroundView = imageView
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tabelView.dataSource = self
    tabelView.delegate = self

    // Request ad
    let request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]

    // Set up ad
    myBanner.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-xxxxxx/xxxxx"
    myBanner.rootViewController = self
    myBanner.delegate = self

    myBanner.load(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run your app in the debug mode, add the device id (you can find it in the console) to the testDevices array:

```
let request = GADRequest()
request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID,  // All simulators
                   "2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b"];  // Sample device ID
```

Now you should be able to test it on your phone.